# ConcurrentDictionary Remove() is not accessible

Tags: c#

So I have this minimal example compiled with .NET 4.7 :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IDictionary<int, string> dic = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>();
        ConcurrentDictionary<int, string> sameDic = (ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>) dic;

        dic.Add(1, "Hold");
        dic.Add(2, "position");

        dic.Remove(1); // OK 
        sameDic.Remove(2); // Not even compiling !! 
    }
}
```

- Is it safe then to call `dic.Remove(1)` ?
- How can I reproduce the same behaviour knowing that the following code is not accepted by the compiler ?

Code :

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void B();
}

public class Bar : IFoo
{
    private void B() // Not allowed 
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: `This behaviour clearly breaks Liskov substitution principle.` Why does it? If you pass a `ConcurrentDictionary` into a method that takes an `IDictionary` it works 100%. Thus it (seems to me) to **not** break LSP.

Comment: `Is it safe then to call dic.Remove(1) ?` Yes. It just calls `TryRemove`.

Comment: `How can I reproduce the same behaviour knowing that the following code is not accepted by the compiler ?` Cast to `IDictionary`, or call `TryRemove`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be looking for [*explicit interface implementation*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation)<sup>1</sup>. You can write:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void B();
}

public class Bar : IFoo
{
    void IFoo.B()
    {
    }
}
```

Now `B` on `Bar` is only accessibly *when accessing a `Bar` as an `IFoo`*.

---

<sup>1</sup>And, indeed, in the `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>` documentation, that's [where you'll find `IDictionary.Remove` listed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx#Explicit%20Interface%20Implementations).

Answer (score 1):

The interface method `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Remove()` is [implemented explicitly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_5) in a `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>`, requiring an interface reference in order to call that method.

Why the .NET Framework team decided to do so is not clear from the documentation, but yes, it's safe to call it because internally it still calls `TryRemove()`.

> How can I reproduce the same behaviour

See [Explicit Interface Implementation (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation).

Comment: A ConcurrentDictionary is not the same as a plain-old Dictionary and shouldn't be passed carelessly anywhere `IDictionary<>` is allowed.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos then it shouldn't implement that interface.

Comment: Why not? The *interface* doesn't give any thread-safety guarantees.

Comment: Then what do you mean? An interface guarantees a contract, not behavior. A ConcurrentDictionary _can_ be used everywhere an `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` is expected. All it does is _add_ thread safety.

Comment: I think the "why" can be inferred from the [`Thread Safety`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx#Thread%20Safety) section. To create a "pit of success", the methods you'll easily find by e.g. intellisense are thread safe. The non-thread safe methods require you to jump through hoops.

Comment: If you know you have a ConcurrentDictionary, you should not be calling Remove on it, because the whole reason you have it is because it's meant to be used in a thread-safe manner (otherwise, just use a Dictionary - it's faster). If you cast a ConcurrentDictionary to an IDictionary, what you are doing is saying "I no longer require thread safety for this dictionary, so I am only going to access it by a single thread at a time.

Comment: @mjwills Oh it is thread-safe to call Remove, but if you were using the ConcurrentDictionary, you should consider the fact that it just "tries", and the value that you are removing at that key depends on how the other threads are using that ConcurrentDictionary.

Comment: @CodeCaster A method that receives a `IDictionary<>` as a parameter will think that it is the only user of that dictionary for the duration of the method (because `IDictionary<>` doesn't guarantee thread safety). While `ConcurrentDictionary<>` is thread safe, it doesn't guarantee repeatable reads. So a method that thinks it is the only user could do: `if (dict["A"] > 0) { Console.WriteLine(dict["A"]); }` (so do multiple access to the same element), but at the same time another thread could legally modify the `dict["A"]` (or remove it)